# emacs lisp and c-mode: when am I in a comment region

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to search for regular expressions within a c/c++ buffer, but I want to avoid expression matching a comment region. Is there a way using the c mode to know if a bunch of text is within a comment region (or a point is within a comment region)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The way to figure that out is with `syntax-ppss` which works in C/C++ and most major modes.  E.g. `(null (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)))` will be non-nil if and only if you're not within a string-or-comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defun re-search-forward-not-in-comment (regexp)
  "Search forward first regexp not inside a comment. "
  (interactive
   (list (read-from-minibuffer "Regexp: ")))
  (while (and (re-search-forward regexp nil t 1)
          (and (nth 8 (syntax-ppss))(nth 4 (syntax-ppss))))))
```

Comment: Please provide more than just a link.

Comment: You can fix your answer by pasting the code here.  This way the answer will still be useful after the link has rotted.

Comment: If you like it, why not copying it, it's free.