# How to never expand yasnippets in comments and strings

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, expansion, yasnippet

I'd like to disable YASnippet expansion (for example, `if`) in comments and strings, but don't find how to do that in a generic way.

On [The condition system](https://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-expansion.html#org075c5ff), they say how to do it for Python, but I'd like to get it working for all prog-modes at once, and I'm not aware of any function which tests "in string/comment", independently of the language.

Is there still a way to do so?

Comment: Perhaps you could try testing evaluating `(nth 8 (syntax-ppss))` in other modes to see if it returns `t` or `nil` inside  strings and comments?  I don't know if that would work, but it seems to be what the function you linked to is doing.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815781/emacs-lisp-and-c-mode-when-am-i-in-a-comment-region/12820339#12820339

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using lawlist's suggestion and adding it to `prog-mode-hook`:

```
(defun yas-no-expand-in-comment/string ()
  (setq yas-buffer-local-condition
        '(if (nth 8 (syntax-ppss)) ;; non-nil if in a string or comment
             '(require-snippet-condition . force-in-comment)
           t)))
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'yas-no-expand-in-comment/string)
```